# How to programmatically set a term to a Woocommerce product variation?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I would like to set all variable products, when created, with the same six different variations using an already defined attribute ("bidragsstorlek"). The six variations should have different prices.

With my current code I succeded with all steps except the last one. I succefully added an attribute, six diffrent terms and six different variations. When I look in the back end panel the product variations have the prices I want, the only thing missing is to set the right term to each variation.

I know similar questions been asked before and been trying to implement those answers, but can't get it right.

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_bidragsstorlek';    
$arrtermnames = array('50 kronor', '100 kronor', '250 kronor', '500 kronor', '1000 kronor', '5000 kronor');

        $attr_data = Array(
            $taxonomy=>Array(
                'name' => $taxonomy,
                'value' => '',
                'is_visible' => '1',
                'is_variation' => '1',
                'is_taxonomy' => '1'
            )
        );

        $newproduct = new WC_Product($product_id);

        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', array_merge($newproduct->get_attributes(), $attr_data) );




foreach ($arrtermnames as &$value) {

$term_name = $value; // The term "NAME"
$term_slug = sanitize_title($term_name); // The term "slug"

// Check if the term exist and if not it create it (and get the term ID).
if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) ){
    $term_data = wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy );
    $term_id   = $term_data['term_id'];
} else {
    $term_id   = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->term_id;
}

// get an instance of the WC_Product Object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$attributes = (array) $product->get_attributes();

// 1. If the product attribute is set for the product
if( array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $attributes ) ) {
    foreach( $attributes as $key => $attribute ){
        if( $key == $taxonomy ){
            $options = (array) $attribute->get_options();
            $options[] = $term_id;
            $attribute->set_options($options);
            $attributes[$key] = $attribute;
            break;
        }
    }
    $product->set_attributes( $attributes );
}
// 2. The product attribute is not set for the product
else {
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

    $attribute->set_id( sizeof( $attributes) + 1 );
    $attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
    $attribute->set_options( array( $term_id ) );
    $attribute->set_position( sizeof( $attributes) + 1 );
    $attribute->set_visible( true );
    $attribute->set_variation( false );
    $attributes[] = $attribute;

    $product->set_attributes( $attributes );
}

$product->save();

// Append the new term in the product
if( ! has_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, $product_id ))
    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $term_slug, $taxonomy, true );

}

unset($value);




$parent_id = $product_id;

$arrprice = array(50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000);



for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {

$variation = array(
    'post_title'   => 'Product #' . $parent_id. $arrprice[$x],
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'post_parent'  => $parent_id,
    'post_type'    => 'product_variation'
);
// The variation id
$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );

update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $arrprice[$x] );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $arrtermnames[$x] );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_virtual', '1' );
// Assign the size and color of this variation
update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $arrtermnames[$x] );

WC_Product_Variable::sync( $parent_id );

}
```

Right now with this code, when checking in the panel, I have a drop-down at each variation with all the terms - but none is choosen. Any idea what is missing to make each variation to be set to the right term?